# How to make a jumping impulse

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a swift game in which i need to apply an impulse to a bar (rectangle), but i don't want the bar to be affected by gravity when the impulse is applied because right now you need to tap the screen like 4 times for the bar to lift when it is falling, any solutions?? My game is called Re-Turn on the AppStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
var affectedByGravity: Bool
```

to `false`. Right away from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/affectedByGravity). But beware, once the velocity zeros out, your node simply stops moving, i.e. it does not fall (because there is no more gravity). Another option would be to make the impulse more strong.

Comment: I think i saw once a property called friction, does that has something to do?

Comment: Please read the SpriteKit documentation. It is all described in there.

Comment: Thank you, but did you got my idea..? Cause i've already implemented what you said, and yes it works but not the way i expect it to..

Comment: It could be friction, yes. But I currently cannot remember its exact definition. That is why you'd have to look it up and play around with this and other parameters.